# Suddenly getApplicationContext(), getApplication(), this.getApplicationContext() are Missing

Tags: java, android

I'm sure i'm not doing something weird or wrong last night. Last night, I'm still able to `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some String", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);`

But this morning, When I try to debug it again for make sure the application still work like the last test, It show up an error. "Unresolvable...".

When I check my `MainActivity.java` code, the `getApplicationContext()` is red text. (I'm using material ui theme and red text mean error). Then i try to retype it. but, it's not showing the auto-complete of `getApplicationContext()` or kind of that. I'm not sure what's wrong with my code. I try it in the new project, and it's work fine.

Here's My Files Code :

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.belajar.belajar1">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context="com.belajar.belajar1.MainActivity" android:weightSum="1">

    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textDirection="firstStrong"
              android:hint="Title"
              android:id="@+id/inputTitle"
            />

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="Your Note"
            android:id="@+id/inputContent"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SAVE"
            android:onClick="cmdProcess"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.belajar.belajar1;

import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.google.firebase.database.*;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference TestLab1;
    EditText mInputTitle, mInputContent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mInputTitle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputTitle);
        mInputContent = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputContent);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some String", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void cmdProcess(View v)
    {
        Map<String, Object> conditionalMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        map.put(root.push().getKey(),
                new Note(mInputTitle.getText().toString(),mInputContent.getText().toString()));

        if (TestLab1 == null)
        {
            conditionalMap.put("TestLab1", map);
            root.updateChildren(conditionalMap);
        }
        else
        {
            TestLab1.updateChildren(map);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild("TestLab1"))
                {
                    TestLab1 = null;
                }
                else if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("TestLab1"))
                {
                    TestLab1 = dataSnapshot.child("TestLab1").getRef();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
            {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

ScreenShot Evidence : 
[image: Cannot resolve method ScreenShot Evidence]

Comment: tried rebuilding the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw that you are using android studio. 
Sometimes this weird problem happens, a project clean solves the problem for me.

If you're sure about your code is correct, this seems to be an IDE problem, try clean project and invalid IDE cache.